# Does /dev/block/mmcblk0 include an external sd card that has been formatted as internal?

Tags: backup, storage, internal-sd, formatting

I am performing a backup using the following command with a su shell:

`dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/mnt/expand/ee131623-1634-25d1-9f9f-902b68eceaee/mmcblk0.img"`

And I was wondering if this would fail to complete as it would include the backup in the backup?

Is Internally formatted external sd cards included in `mmcblk0`?

Comment: from my understanding this should work and there is no way to include something at block layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Internally formatted external sd card is not included in `mmcblk0`. `dd` dumps files, in your case the block device file `mmcblk0` which includes all partitions, GUID partition table (GPT) and any free space in between partitions.

External SD card is a separate flash memory chip, so exposed by a different block device available at path something like `/dev/block/mmcblk1` or `/dev/block/sda`.

Comment: except for some very old devices (Samsung/Nexus?) they have separate so called "sdcard" partition on mmcblk0 (and additional external MicroSd Card mmcblk1)

Comment: Right. Actually `mmcblk1` is a convention for external SD card and `sda` for USB OTG etc. Yes a separate partition `mmcblk0p*` was used for external storage before `/data/media` was started being emulated.